# Save,Cancel Button Not working in joomla 2.5

Tags: button, joomla, save

I have change something in joomla contact component,basically i d'nt want the editor in contact component instead of this i want to place something,when i have remove the editor,the save,cancel button not functioning.Can anybody know whats the procedure for removing the editor and place my own chart.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you are looking for, visit this web link.

http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Joomla-Fast-Road-to-Understand-Component-Programming-P66.html